# Open a document with Data Point Click or Mark Double Click Lazarus

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I am using Lazarus TAChart component to compare our companies sales vs the advertising we do, The chart shows the value of sales per week and a label with the name of the advertising we have sent to our clients.

The database for the advertising has a label (name of the advertising) and a Link with the location of a pdf file of what we sent to our clients.

Does anyone know if there is a way to open a document by clicking or double click on a TAChart Data Point or by Clinking on the chart label.

I have been looking around but can't find any sample code on how to do it.

Sincerely, 
Derek

Comment: [TAChart Tutorial: Chart Tools](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/TAChart_Tutorial:_Chart_Tools#Using_a_TDataPointClickTool)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the comment. any suggestions on how I can select the value on the link Field?